# An example about the checkpoint in windows service status

Tags: c++, windows

I'm new to the Windows API. Recently, I was reading the documentation about the [service status structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/ns-winsvc-service_status), and it said:

> The user interface program that invoked the operation on the service uses this value to track the progress of the service during a lengthy operation. This value is not valid and should be zero when the service does not have a start, stop, pause, or continue operation pending.

I don't quite understand the description in the documentation.

I have searched for information about Windows Service checkpoints, but I haven't found much that discusses this topic. Is there an example that can provide a clearer explanation of the concept? Including a link to a relevant project or a more detailed answer to my question would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Lets say your service needs to do some expensive initialization when started, one that will take long time. The service can then send updates to the service manager to tell it about its progress, so the service manager doesn't think the service have stopped working and needs to be restarted. The progress is simply an increasing value for the `dwCheckPoint` member.